# Recurring Paypal payment with dynamic amount in Standard paypal method

Tags: php, html, paypal

I have one simple PayPal Standard HTML form with 3 textbox and one button .

```
textbox 1 : <Amount pay now>
textbox 2 : <Out standing Amount pay on specific date>
textbox 3 : <recurring payment date>
```

Now when user clicks on a button, it redirects to PayPal for payment process as I have used PayPal standard method.

I want the amount to be processed from textbox1 and another amount should process automatically on a specific date.

Can someone please help out me to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
srt - Recurring times
src - 1 //Subscription payments recur.
sra - 1. Reattempt failed recurring payments before canceling.
a3 -  Regular subscription price.
p3  - Subscription duration. Specify an integer value 
t3  - Regular subscription units of duration.
      Valid range for p3 is 1 to 90 in D. similarly M, etc
business - your business email
item_name - order id / descripiton of item sold
currency_code - USD / INR
```

This is the reference URL

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#recurring-payment-variables

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/html_example_subscribe/#product-options-as-text-boxes

Ex. This sample HTML code illustrates a basic Subscribe button with these features:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/html_example_subscribe/#basic-subscribe-button

- No trial periods. A subscription price of $5.00 USD. A monthly
  billing cycle. The subscription ends only when the merchant or
  subscriber cancels it.

Answer (score -1):

This isn't a simple bit of programming.

Why don't you use a third party like Stripe to handle this for you? It's built in and will be a lot easier for you to setup and you could focus on creating a decent custom dashboard where you could pull via the API of Stripe customer information and opportunity to change/cancel their subscription?